# Python index error at amount = int(range[1])-int(range[0])

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to split a range of numbers like 1230-1236 so each number is named separately.

```
#if number is just a number write a name with that number
 if num.isdigit():
 photonum = str(num)
#add 0's to photo number until it is 4 digits long
 while len(photonum) < 4:
 photonum = "0"+photonum 
#write name using parts created 
 g.write(parts[0] + prefix +":"+ parts[1] +"_"+ parts[2] +"_"+ date +"_" + "(" + svf[0:5] + ")" + "_" +photonum+"\n")

#if number is a range, split it into two parts then write a name for every number between those parts                   
else:
range = num.split("-")
amount = int(range[1])-int(range[0])
c=0
while c<=amount:
photonum = str(int(range[0])+c)
while len(photonum) < 4:
photonum = "0"+photonum 
#write name using parts created 
g.write(parts[0] + prefix +":"+ parts[1] +"_"+ parts[2] +"_"+ date +"_" + "(" + svf[0:5] + ")" + "_" +photonum+"\n")
c+=1
```

I keep getting an IndexError: List index out of range for this line amount = int(range[1])-int(range[0])

Any idea what is causing this

Comment: please fix code indentation

Comment: a sidenote: be careful when using names of built-ins (ex: `range = num.split("-")`) because they will override the name of the built-in in that scope, causing unexpected behavior - consider altering the name to something unique like `my_range` or `num_range`

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. what is `num`? a string? I tried `num = '1230-1236';
range = num.split("-");
amount = int(range[1])-int(range[0]); print amount` and got `6` as output.

Comment: I figured it out. It was simply a matter of the text file I was drawing from being too large. I deleted half the list and it worked. Go figure. Thank you for your help

Comment: cool, glad to hear you solved it and got it working, cheers!